# Could past simple fit in this case ?("question" in past perfect answer in past simple)

Tags: past-tense

I ordered a copy of this new record on vinyl and postage was only 1,6 euros( it should have been around 10 euros)  .Surprised  I just double-checked to see if  I **had chosen** the good option . Yes I **chose** the good one!

Can I use past simple for "yes I chose the good option " or would it be better to use past perfect as I chose in  the previous sentence.In this previous sentence "had chosen" is justified because it happens  before I double-checked but in the last sentence there is no reason to use past perfect.Am I right?

Comment: The comma for a decimal is not used in English, and will cause confusion (it looks like "one or six Euros".)  You would write €1.60 in English (with the euro sign first and 60 for 60 cents).

Answer (score 1):

Native speakers generally avoid *repeated* use of Past Perfect.

You only need *one* instance to unambiguously set the temporal relationships between the *primary* Past Tense setting of a narrative / conversation and something that came *before* that.

So ***chose*** is fine for the cited context.